# Why can't I change a dropdown icon?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't change my dropdown icon from the default "carrot" to a Fontawesome one.

I have read other questions, and yet none will work for me.

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <select disabled class="custom-select">
   <option selected>Región Metropolitana</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <select class="custom-select">
   <option selected>Comuna</option>
   <option>One</option>
   <option>Two</option>
   <option>Three</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>


.form-group .custom-select:disabled {
   background: none;
}

.form-group .custom-select::after {
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9;
  color: red;
}
```

My dropdown should show this fontawesome icon: https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-down?style=solid

[image: This is how it is showing]

[image: This is how I need it]

Comment: you taged your question with [bootstrap-4] so why don't you use the bootstrap-way to build dropdowns? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ::after with select. I had the same problem as you. The best way to do it is with a CSS background image to customise the arrow. Such as:

```
select {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../Images/Generic/arrowDownBlack.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 5px center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none; //This gets rid of the arrow in IE.
}
```

If you use a vector image it will be just as good as font awesome.

To prove that I'm right you could always try adding the ::after to another element. It will show up, just not with select.